# Is there a specific name for this special case of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

Consider the most general real symmetric 2 × 2 matrix

$$
    A = \begin{pmatrix}
    a & c \\
    c & b \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, if the diagonal terms are equal i.e., $a = b$, which can be written as below. Is there a specific name that is used for such a symmetric matrix?

$$
    A = \begin{pmatrix}
    b & c \\
    c & b \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Note: We end up with equal diagonal and equal anti-diagonal terms but cannot generalise this for any n x n matrix since for any higher-order square matrix there will always be one common element for the diagonal and anti-diagonal terms.

Comment: It would be nice if you can at least react to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia knows [bisymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisymmetric_matrix) and [centrosymmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrosymmetric_matrix) matrices.